# how to read properties file in clojure so that there no body can see my data-base password

Tags: clojure

In java we read the properties file by
Myclass.class.getProtectionDomain.getCodesource.getLocation.getPath()

But how this read in clojure

Answer (score 2):

Demo on different class:

```
(def clazz clojure.lang.PersistentVector)
(.. clazz getProtectionDomain getCodeSource getLocation getPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ClojureWerkz's propertied library : 
http://blog.clojurewerkz.org/blog/2013/10/07/introducing-propertied/

Propertied is a tiny Clojure library that makes working with Java property lists from Clojure a bit nicer.

It is very small in scope: convert java.util.Properties to and from an immutable map, load and store them to and from .properties files.